# Is there any way to do background tasks in React Native other than react-native-background-task?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, background-task

I'm trying to do in my React Native App that each X min the app fetch some data of my application included if the app is closed. Or more similar, each X min I want to save a value in the `AsyncStorage`.

It suppose that the `react-native-background-task` does that but, unfortunately, the project is abandoned with a lot of errors and bugs that make using it unviable.

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Did you try Headless js?

Comment: @MasukHelalAnik Headless js is only for android and I need both platforms :(

Comment: @SmoggeR_js have you managed to find a solution for both OS?

Comment: No, I didn't...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For android, background service works fine which has its RN implementation in form of `Headless JS task`. For iOS, there is no such ready made library to be used in RN. iOS being restrictive doesn't allows applications to take on the job queue control of OS straight away, though in native OS API, there are ways such things as per the business requirements.

You can refer [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) to better understand which option to use for your use-case and can come up with a bridging module for RN as well.

Comment: After search a lot of info about of it, my conclusion was your answer, that's the reason I made this answer the correct one. Anyway, is sadly to see that we are not able to do that kind of stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `react-native-queue`.I think it will suit your requirement.

[Click here For complete guide](https://github.com/billmalarky/react-native-queue#os-background-task-full-example).

You can try `react-native-background-job`too.

[Click Here for Complete Guide](https://github.com/vikeri/react-native-background-job)

Comment: If you focus on it, you could see that it have a lot of issues and it uses react-native-background-task so I won't work. That was about react-native-queue. And about background-job, that's only for android

Comment: it seems you will have to  reuse some existing Java code and use in react native.https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html

Comment: Anyway... The real problem is not Android, is iOS!